# Is there any solution to get g:pagination and g:sortableColumn for children elements in parents show view working?

Tags: grails, gsp

Is there any simple solution to get g:pagination <s>and g:sortableColumn</s> for children elements in parent show view working?

It is well explained in the documentation how to do pagination <s>and sortable columns</s> for current domain in list, and it works, but I cant get it to work in situation described in question.

**Edit: I updated the example**

Now only thing that is not working is pagination. When I click on the next page link the list is gone and ${childrenistSize} prints 0.

**Simple example:**

**Parent domain**

```
class Parent {

    String name

    static hasMany = [children: Children]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

**Children domain**

```
class Children {

    String first
    int number

    static belongsTo = [parent: Parent]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

**Parent list view**

```
<g:each in="${parentList}" var="parent">
    <tr>
        <td>${parent.name}</td>
        <td><g:link controller="parent" action="show" id="${parent.id}">Show</g:link></td>
    </tr>
</g:each>
```

**Parent show view**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <g:sortableColumn property="first" title="First"/>
            <g:sortableColumn property="number" title="Number"/>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <g:each in="${childrenList}" var="child">
            <tr>
                <td>${child.first}</td>
                <td>${child.number}</td>
            </tr>
        </g:each>
    </tbody>
</table>
<g:paginate total="${childrenListSize}"/>
```

**ParentController**

```
class ParentController {

    def index() { }

    def list() {
        [parentList: Parent.list()]

    }

    def show() {
        params.max=3
        def parentInstance = Parent.get(params.id)
        def childrens = Children.createCriteria().list(params) {
          eq('parent', parentInstance)
        }
        [parentInstance : parentInstance , childrenList: childrens, childrenListSize: childrens.totalCount]
     }

}
```

**Some BootStrap test elements**

```
    Parent parent1 = new Parent(name: "TestParent1")
    Parent parent2 = new Parent(name: "TestParent2")

    Children child1 = new Children(first: "Bob", number: "1")
    Children child2 = new Children(first: "John", number: "2")
    Children child3 = new Children(first: "Igor", number: "3")
    Children child4 = new Children(first: "Lucy", number: "4")
    Children child5 = new Children(first: "Lisa", number: "5")

    Children child6 = new Children(first: "Bob", number: "12")
    Children child7 = new Children(first: "John", number: "24")
    Children child8 = new Children(first: "Igor", number: "33")
    Children child9 = new Children(first: "Lucy", number: "42")

    parent1.addToChildren(child1).addToChildren(child2).addToChildren(child3).addToChildren(child4).addToChildren(child5)
    parent2.addToChildren(child6).addToChildren(child7).addToChildren(child8).addToChildren(child9)

    parent1.save()
    child1.save()
    child2.save()
    child3.save()
    child4.save()
    child5.save()
    parent2.save()
    child6.save()
    child7.save()
    child8.save()
    child9.save()
```

Comment: So what's the question? what's not working?

Comment: The question is: how to get this to work in situation like in my example, because the pagination and sortableColumn right now is not working. It is easy to implement the pagination and sortableColumn in Parent list view for parent elements, or in Children list view for children elements, but it doesn't work in situation I described in my question post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have a column named `children.name` in the Children domain class. What you need to do is identify in your controller that you must sort by the name column.

I can see that you show a list of childrens in the `show` action of Parent, and the parent isn't sortable in this action, so will be a simple change:

```
def show() {
  def parentInstance = Parent.get(params.id)
  def childrens = Children.createCriteria().list(params) {
    eq('parent', parentInstance)
  }
  [parentInstance : parentInstance , childrenList: childrens, childrenListSize: childrens.totalCount]
}


<p>Parent: ${parentInstance.name}</p>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <g:sortableColumn property="name" title="Name"/>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <g:each in="${childrenList}" var="child">
            <tr>
                <td>${child.name}</td>
            </tr>
        </g:each>
    </tbody>
</table>
<g:paginate max="1" total="${childrenListSize}"/>
```

Note that I changed the `property name` since it's just name and not children.name. Also, i pass the params to the criteria to make the sort works.

I not tested this, so can be a typo anywhere.

Comment: The changes you suggested get the sortable columns to work with the exception of column with Int elements (like Int age in Children domain object) - it just sort it in random order every time I click it. The pagination is still missing (there is even no controls visible for it).

Comment: Double check the `property` attribute in `g:sortable` or update your question, because there's no integers there.

Comment: My bad, please ignore the integer part. What about pagination? Can you point me in right direction?

Comment: What's the value of `childrenListSize`? Print it in the view.

Comment: I didn't see any error in your g:paginate call. If you set params.max in the controller and remove the max param of the tag works?

Comment: When I move the max parameter to controller the list is trimmed to the number of max elements I specify in params.max, but there are no navigation buttons for pagination.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20691/discussion-between-sergio-michels-and-tv)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have answer to my question:

<s>.createCryteria solves only the column sorting problem, so you need to add in the show action of parent controller this line of code:</s>

```
def totalChildrenListSize = Children.findAllByParents(parentInstance, [params])
```

to get list of all children, that specific parent have, so you can get the size by calling .size() ([...., totalChildrenListSize: totalChildrenListSize.size()] method on it.

call the totalCount on childrens as Sergio suggested, and next set up param.max for that show action and change pagination tag adding the id parameter:

```
<g:paginate id="${parentInstance.id}" total="${totalChildrenListSize}"/>
```

Comment: `childrens.totalCount` do the same as the findAll, because don't apply the limit.

Comment: Thank you, this way it is shorter and still works. I will update my question with working example.